# How to share links that don't open in in-app browsers?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, webview, youtube

I want to share the link of my YouTube channel on Facebook and Instagram. Both these apps have built-in browsers that open the link within these apps. Most people are not logged in to these in-app browsers and hence are unable to subscribe easily. I know that the settings within the apps can be changed so that the links open externally but not everyone knows this or is willing to do so. Neither does everyone know that the links can be opened in the YouTube app with 2 clicks after it's opened in the in-app browser. As a result, many people who are willing to subscribe to my channel are unable to do so due to technical reasons. Is there any way I can create and share links that don't open in in-app browsers?